# What is the order of precedence for modulus in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, operator-precedence, modulus

If I have the following code

```
var num = 15 % 2 + 6 * 4;
```

for example... I'd like to know what the output will be, specifically I would like to know the order of precedence for modulus (the operation executed by the `%` symbol). Will the modulus be performed before or after the addition and multiplication operations?

**Edit**: I have already looked at the article people are linking me to

[MDN Operator Precedence](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Operator_Precedence)

And had done so before asking the question, but unfortunately it didn't contain enough information to completely answer my question, hence my asking here. Just to save people the effort of linking again.

*Update*: Looking into [associativity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operator_associativity) as indications from discussion in the comments beneath one proposed answer are that the question is associated with associativity (if you'll pardon the accidental pun).

*Update*: Syntax edit (^_^?)

Comment: Why don't you try?

Comment: This is something you really should be just [looking up](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Operator_Precedence) rather than answering on Stackoverflow.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Operator_Precedence shows modulus as having the same precedence as division and multiplication commands, yet I want to know which will occur first, the multiplication or the modulus, or if there are perhaps some additional variables governing which might occur first.

Comment: Regarding the output, using http://labs.codecademy.com I get the ```num``` variable value of ```25``` with the example code, yet ```var num = 3 * 15 % 2 + 6 * 4;``` also results in a ```num``` variable which a ```console.log``` shows as also bearing the value ```25```...

Comment: Clearly the table you've looked at says that `%` has a higher precedence than `+`. So what is the problem?

Comment: No problem. I just want to understand the full implications of modulus order of precedence, not just the example itself which may only tell a partial story :~).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Technically it's the [*remainder* operator](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/index.html#sec-applying-the-mod-operator) (more mathematical minds than mine say modulus would handle sign differences differently), and it has the same precedence and associativity as multiplication and division.

So

```
var num = 15 % 2 + 6 * 4;
```

is

```
var num = (15 % 2) + (6 * 4);
```

MDN has [a handy article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Operator_Precedence) on operator precedence and associativity.

---

Re your comment on the question:

> ...I get the `num` variable value of `25` with the example code, yet `var num = 3 * 15 % 2 + 6 * 4;` also results in a `num` variable which a `console.log` shows as also bearing the value of `25`...

That's because both `15 % 2 + 6 * 4` and `3 * 15 % 2 + 6 * 4` are `25`. Let's break it down:

Your first example: `15 % 2 + 6 * 4`

```
15 % 2 + 6 * 4
1      + 6 * 4
1      + 24
25
```

Your second example: `3 * 15 % 2 + 6 * 4`

```
3 * 15 % 2 + 6 * 4
45     % 2 + 6 * 4
1          + 6 * 4
1          + 24
25
```

Comment: So they are executed in the same order the compiler parses them?

Comment: @PeterDavidCarter: No, they're executed in the order defined by the language spec, which is quite different. The compiler will parse those in the order `%`, `+`, and `*`, but they'll execute in the order `%`, `*`, `+`. The order in which they're *parsed* is irrelevant here.

Comment: So the remainder operator (modulus/```%```) will execute before the multiplication operator (```*```) is what you appear to be saying? Am I reading you correctly here?

Comment: @PeterDavidCarter: Only in your specific original example. Again, `%` has the same precedence as `*` and `/`. If you have multiple operators with the same precedence, they'll be processed in the order they appear, before operations with lower precedence like `+` or `-` are processed. So `1 * 2 % 3` is `(1 * 2) % 3` (2) but `1 + 2 % 3` is `1 + (2 % 3)` (3).

Comment: So the order they appear on the screen when writing the code will not necessarily be the order they are parsed? I had always assumed Javascript parses left to right; is there more to it?

Comment: @PeterDavidCarter: Again, parsing is irrelevant here; it's *execution* that's relevant. Yes, most math (not all) is left-to-right associative, but precedence trumps associativity. I should point out that this basically has nothing to do with JavaScript; JavaScript just follows the conventions of basic arithmetic with regard to the basic operators. The rule is called PEMDAS in some places, BODMAS in others. (And should be written PE(MD)(AS) or BO(DM)(AS) as the M and D in both cases have the same precedence, as do A and S.)

Comment: Ah, so hence we follow BODMAS logic because modulus is a subset of the division operation and hence occurs before the multiplication operation? So why in your example do the multiplication operations not BOTH occur before the division subset operation (modulus)?

Comment: Or, if we use your alternative formulation (BO(DM)(AS) INSTEAD of BODMAS), then we are back to left-right and/or order of parsing being the criteria for order of operation, surely?

Comment: @PeterDavidCarter: *"So why in your example do the multiplication operations not BOTH occur before the division subset operation (modulus)?"* If you're talking about `3 * 15 % 2 + 6 * 4`, because the `3 * 15` is leftmost, and the `(result) % 2` is then leftmost. I can't guarantee that the `(result) % 2` is done before `6 *4` because it doesn't make any difference to the result, but I'm fairly sure it isn't.

Comment: So the order of execution among _documentarily_ simultaneously occurring Javascript operations is left to right, in the same direction as I assume the compiler parses, correct?

Comment: @PeterDavidCarter clearly in the examples in this question it doesn't really make a mathematical difference (ignoring for now possible floating-point issues); what is it you're *really* trying to determine? Do you have expressions with side-effects? Are you in fact concerned about floating-point issues?

Comment: I found an example in a tech test and I wanted to understand what how modulus functions within Javascript so I am prepared for the next phases of the application process and any possible interview questions surrounding the subject.

Comment: @PeterDavidCarter: *"simultaneously occurring Javascript operations is left to right, in the same direction as I assume the compiler parses, correct?"* For the third time: **Parsing has nothing to do with this.** And no, it's not correct. Again, there's *associativity*. Most math operations are left-to-right associative, but not all. I suggest that if you really need to get into the depths of this, you find a good arithmetic textbook that discusses the concepts of precedence and associativity.

Comment: So, what's the difference between Javascript parsing left to right and  Javascript being a left-associative language, assuming both assumptions are correct??

Comment: Could you maybe give a practical example of the difference between left-right (or right-left or whatever :) ) parsing and left-right/right-left associativity? It might be useful for future learning :).

Answer (score 1):

Modulo should have the same precedence as division, multiplication, and exponents. See [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Operator_Precedence)

Answer (score 1):

Basically you going left to right but you're doing plus first, then multiply, then divide, and the remainder stuff is divide. So

```
 var num = 15 % 2 + 6 * 4;
```

is basically 15 % 2 = 1

Comment: It will give you 25 but the answer will be one first :)